# How to set secondaryProgress programatically in widget in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

Need to show primary and secondary progress in a widget.

RemoteViews class has below method in which I can pass maximum and progress value but not secondaryProgress.

```
remoteViews.setProgressBar(R.id.pbHorizontal, 100, 50, false);
```

Any hint or suggestion would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method as far as I can see, but you can set int property 
of a view manually with `RemoteViews`.

There is a method [setInt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setInt(int,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

```
setInt(viewId, "setSecondaryProgress", secondaryProgress);
```

`setProgressBar()` uses it [under the hood](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/RemoteViews.java)